# Is it possible to convert stream to buffer synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, gulp, gulp-tap

Look at the simplest Gulp task that uses [gulp-tap](https://github.com/geejs/gulp-tap):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var tap = require('gulp-tap');    

gulp.task('mytask', function () {
    return gulp.src("src/*/*.js")
        .pipe(tap(function (file) {
            file.contents = new Buffer('blabla');        
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

It takes files from the `src` directory, replaces content with "blabla" and saves those "spoiled" files to the "dist" directory. It's easy!

But what if we have stream instead of the "blabla"? For example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var tap = require('gulp-tap');
var jsdocParse= require("jsdoc-parse");  

gulp.task('jsdoc', function () {
  return gulp.src("src/*/*.js")
    .pipe(tap(function (file) {
      var stream = jsdocParse(file.path);
      file.contents = ???;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Comment: No, you cannot do that synchronously. You'll need some higher-order stream combinators.

Comment: Could you give a link or write sort example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
gulp.task('mytask', function () {
    return gulp.src("src/*.js")
        .pipe(tap(function (file, t) {
          file.contents = Buffer.concat([
                jsdocParse(file.path)
            ]);
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```